# Adding anonymous IURS IIS user fails into SQL SERVER 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server, iis, iis-7, sql-server-2008

I am trying to add a anonymous IIS user [IUSR] to a SQL SERVER 2008 r2 database.

But I am getting the following error:

'notebook/iusr' is not a valid login or you do not have permission.

I think permission is not the issue because I am logged with the 'sa' account.
Also I tried only 'iusr' as a username and I get the same error?

Does anyone have some idea on how to add the IIS7 anonymous account to a sql server 2208 r2 database?

Comment: Could not find a work around for that. I´ve just set iis7 app pool to run under local user administrator.

Answer (score 0):

This is called a managed service account (MSA).You have to add a dollar sign ($) after the username when creating the login. The format is DOMAIN\ACCOUNTNAME$. I believe you'll have to script this login out, as the GUI search feature won't find it.

```
CREATE LOGIN [DOMAIN\MACHINENAME$] FROM WINDOWS
```

Answer (score 0):

IUSR is a built-in local account for Windows Server 2008 and higher.

Instead of NOTEBOOK\IUSR

Use BUILTIN\IUSR